# Set off Vs Set out

Tags: phrasal-verbs

He set out southwestward,made his way after great hardships to Palestine,found one friend there and set off again toward the west.
                                                (By Philip Khuri Hitti)
I couldn't understand why didn't the writer use set out and set off alternatively?

Comment: Sorry? I'm not understanding your question. The writer *had* used "set out" and "set off" alternatively, no? For [variation](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/elegant-variatio/), most likely? If you mean why the author hadn't used "set off" first and "set out" second, he could've, but he had probably just liked it better this way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary: there is no difference between these two phrasal verbs:

[set off](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set-off) - to start on a trip

[set out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set-out) -to start a journey

I can think of no particular reason why he should use one form in preference to the other. As TeacherKSHuang suggested, he might have alternated their use for variety, but changing just the adverb half of a phrasal verb does not give a lot of variety.

Note that Philip Khuri Hitti was born and raised in Lebanon, although he moved to America in his twenties, where he taught Arabic. It may be that he was trying to express some distinction that is better defined in his mother tongue.

Answer (score 0):

The above is right but let's remember "set off" also has a different definition and is wayyyy more versatile.

Set off fireworks, set off the smoke alarm.. You obviously can't say "set out the smoke alarm". You can say that but it would mean you just took it out of your drawer or whatever and placed it in plain sight.

Comment: While this is true, the question is specifically about journeys.